# Input only month and year, stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my stored procedure we have to input the 2013-12-12 to get data. Now with a new system we only want to use month and year to get the correct data. We use Microsoft SQL server 2008.

This is how we get data today:

```
exec dbo.Month '2013-12-12'
```

This is how we want the input to be to get data:

```
exec dbo.Month '2013-12'
```

-- @dateStr format yyyy-mm-dd

Possible to change?

I don't really know where in the database to start looking, and the stored procedure is to big to start adding here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type for only a datapart of the date. You can of course change the input parameter to varchar() of some size and then do the necessary format inside the SP with 'Convert' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). But it is not really that nice a solution.